# Unable to run NUXT on Ubuntu server - node_modules/unplugin-element-plus/dist/vite.mjs dose not exist

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I want to run my Nuxt application on Ubuntu server but it is not working. (Work normally on Local machine).

Here is the error,

```
Nuxt 3.7.1 with Nitro 2.6.2                                                                                                                                                                 5:48:20 AM
                                                                                                                                                                                            5:48:21 AM
  ➜ Local:    http://localhost:5000/
  ➜ Network:  use --host to expose

ℹ Using default Tailwind CSS file                                                                                                                                         nuxt:tailwindcss 5:48:24 AM
ℹ Tailwind Viewer: http://localhost:5000/_tailwind/                                                                                                                       nuxt:tailwindcss 5:48:24 AM
[nuxt] Could not resolve id fsevents /home/thor/project/frontend-web/node_modules/unplugin-element-plus/dist/vite.mjs                                                               5:48:34 AM

 ERROR  Failed to resolve import "fsevents" from "node_modules/unplugin-element-plus/dist/vite.mjs". Does the file exist?
```

I've already checked the 'node_modules/unplugin-element-plus/dist/vite.mjs' and it dose exist. I already tempted to remove node_modules and re-install. It is still not working.

Please help